# Can you someone Java expert please explain me how the following output is erroneous?

Tags: java

This the code I am referring to How it produces such erroneous output your detailed explanation required

[image]

Comment: What is erroneous about the output?

Comment: Please, alway write the code instead of pasting a picture. It is difficult to help you in this way.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There is **no code in the constructor**, so the fields remain unassigned, i.e. keep their default values of `null` and `0`. *To fix:* Implement the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for the question. [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1):

As per of my understanding, I think you must initialise your private variables in Person constructor like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person
{
private String name;
private int age;

public Person(String name, int age)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public int getAge()
{
    return age;
}
public String toString()
{
    return name+" aged "+age;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    
    List<Person>accounts=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=1;i<=5;i++ )
    {
        Person person = new Person("Name0" + i, 10+7*i);
        accounts.add(person);
        System.out.println(person);
    }
    
  }

 }
```

So the output in this case will be:

```
Name01 aged 17
Name02 aged 24
Name03 aged 31
Name04 aged 38
Name05 aged 45
```

If you want to print ArrayList<>() object instead of printing Person class object you will get the output like below:

```
[Name01 aged 17]
[Name01 aged 17, Name02 aged 24]
[Name01 aged 17, Name02 aged 24, Name03 aged 31]
[Name01 aged 17, Name02 aged 24, Name03 aged 31, Name04 aged 38]
[Name01 aged 17, Name02 aged 24, Name03 aged 31, Name04 aged 38, 
 Name05 aged 45]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the list reference instead of the Person one. If you want to print the List contents you can iterate it after the for but in this case you can change the code of the **for** to this, so you are printing the created object.

```
for(int i = 0, i<5; i++){
   Person person = new Person("Name0" + i, 10+7*i));
   accountList.add(person);
   System.out.println(person);
}
```

Comment: I believe that the original questioner printed the entire list on purpose. Then each person came out wrong. You are printing only one person at a time, and that person will still come out wrong. You aren’t solving any problem nor answering the question. (Not your downvoter.) (And if the OP had posted code as text, you could have tried it yourself.)

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear, talking about "erroneous output" without explaining what's erroneous about it. Looking at the question, I find that `null` and `0` in the output to be obviously erroneous, and that the printing of the entire list on the loop to likely just be for debugging purposes, and hence not necessarily errorneous. As such, this answer doesn't address the main problem at all, and is therefore not useful, so I down-voted. Sorry I forgot to leave a comment explaining why.